# What is purpose of correlation kernel? IIs it high pass filter or low pass filter?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, filters, data-analysis, image-processing

I am research about correlation kernel and I have some questions that need your help. Let see the pp. 3302-3303 in the http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6517250&tag=1 The special kernel is defined that
[image]
where $\gamma$ is a normalizing weight obtained by
[image]

and $\omega$ is Gaussian kernel

I implement it with support from Mr. Rayryeng. This is comparison of gaussian filter (right side)and correlation filter(left side). The gaussian looks like the low pass filter, whereas correlation kernel is as high pass filter. Could you help me explain the purpose of correlation kernel comparison with gaussian kernel? Which is beneifit? What kind of image to apply correlation kernel. Thank you

[image]

Consider image segmentation task, what do you think which is best for below image

[image]

Comment: $\omega$ is the size parameter of the kernel, not the kernel itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe that $\frac1{1+t}\approx1-t$ for $t$ not too large, you see that this filter subtracts a Gauss-low-passed image from the original, and is indeed a high-pass.

The purpose is probably to reduce the slope (slow illumination changes) in the uniform areas while preserving edge information, to facilitate segmentation.

Comment: Anyway, I can't understand why they call it a correlation filter.

Comment: In the paper, the author said that "Instead of using parameters to balance the image noise and the image details as the pre-processing step of the conventional algorithms, for
instance, the advantage of W(|y − x|) is that it is less
dependent on the parameter setting." I don't think that sentence is correct. Anyway, I agree that it is high pass filter not correlation kernel. For image segmentation, which kind of image that use high pass fiter, sir?

Comment: When illumination is uneven.

Comment: Yes, It is inhomogeneity image, due to non-uniform noise, ...

Comment: Sorry, non-uniform noise (nor uniform) noise is suppressed by a high pass filter as it contains only high frequencies.

Comment: That means it is better if we apply high filter for this case,right?

Comment: What "this" case, please be specific ?

Comment: The non-uniform noise case. It is shown by figure in my question

Comment: No a high pass filter does not help suppress noise at all, on  the opposite.

Comment: What do you think which is best filter in my image(shown in question)?Thanks

Comment: There is no single answer. It depends what you want to do with this image. For instance if you want to extract the regions by thresholding, then high pass filtering is mandatory. On the opposite, if you want to do edge detection, high pass filtering is  useless, as edge detection performs yet stronger high pass.

Comment: Yes sir, I want to segment the three regions from image, From your recommend, I think I will use high pass filtering.